# Does a market/shop with fully legal 8-bit software/games exist?

Tags: software, 8-bit-microcomputers

Currently about all of "8-bit micro" games that I know is either abandonware (which is a gray area) or free fan works. But is there some kind of shop, market, some place where you can purchase these games, or other software fully legally for money? Some kind of retro-shop, or such?

Comment: There is just not going to be one good answer to this question, because the question "what vendors exist for all 8-bit micros" is much too broad and much to ephemeral to attract good answers. All we are going to get are forum style answers that consist of nothing more than links. This hits the "too broad", "SE is not a shopping service" and "SE is not a software recommendation service" buttons for SE sites. SE, in general, is not a good place for these types of requests.

Comment: @jdv: I really didn't expect such a wide response, expecting 0 to 1 answers; the question is actually binary, yes/no, so any single answer is sufficient. Though in the current shape I believe it would be best to make it a community wiki.

Comment: Also, I can't help but feel that if we are going to accept such questions, perhaps intended as Wiki/forum style questions, they should be less broad (i.e., at least more platform specific). This is obvious from the Answers that are prefaced with 'for the XYZ system you can find Frobnication software here...'

Comment: @jdv: I honestly didn't expect even one answer, that's why I asked it so broadly.

Comment: The point of SE sites are to ask *specific* questions to get good, detailed answers that address that question. This creates content in a Q&A format that is not only helpful to you, but for others in the foreseeable future. IMO, this question does not satisfy that intention.

Comment: The acceptability of this kind of question should be decided in meta. At best, some "resources" posting could be created and maintained there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few... On the homebrew front for example, the [AtariAge store](https://www.atariage.com/store/) sells packaged homebrew games for 8-bit Ataris (and now Intellivision), as does [pro(c)](https://proc-atari.de/en/software-boardgames) (along with its magazine). You can also find stores which still have "old new" stock of games, computers and accessories; for example [Best Electronics](http://best-electronics-ca.com/text.htm) for Atari computers and consoles. There are no doubt others for other platforms!

Answer (score 7):

For the ZX Spectrum and MSX there is Matranet, which sells physical versions (e.g. tapes and cartridges) of recent releases.
http://www.matranet.net/boutique/boutique.php

Answer (score 7):

C64 wise, you have [RGCD](http://rgcd.co.uk/) who sell new cartridge releases, along with [Psytronik Software](http://psytronik.net) and [Protovision](http://www.protovision-online.com) who both have releases on disk, whilst Psytronik also offer tape copies as well.

For the BBC Micro/Electron, there's [Retro Software](http://www.retrosoftware.co.uk), who offer some as well.

Answer (score 4):

For the Apple II, there aren't any one-stop shop type places for software, but if you go to the big sites like A2Central.com, you'll find links to companies still selling their software, and to shareware vendors still kicking (like myself).

Answer (score 2):

[Relevo](http://www.relevovideogames.com/) is a Spanish company that develops videogames for both modern game consoles [and 8 bit computers](http://www.relevovideogames.com/retrogames-2/) (especially MSX). Although they offer the games as free downloads, there is also the option to purchase them as physical cartridges from [Matranet](http://www.matranet.net/boutique/buy.php).